# Line break not woking with Wordpress TinyMCE Advanced

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I have a word document, with all my posts already write on it.
So I just have to copy/paste all these posts on my tinyMCE advanced Editor in my Wordpress 4.1

The only problem is that it doesn't take care about line break when I echo them in my blog page.. Whereas I can see these line break on tinyMCE visual preview. And if I check in the tinyMCE text mode, I don't see any `<br />` or any `<p>` tags.

Does anyone had this problem ?

I have created my own template. And it is my first time on Wordpress so I could have miss something, but everyone seems to have a problem with `remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');` in their **function.php** But I don't have this function and I try with `add_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');` but it doesn't change anything.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your themes template where you output `the_content` try this:

```
$getPost = get_the_content();
$postformatted = wpautop( $getPost );
echo $postformatted;
```

You may want to remove the filter you added if it does not initially work.

Comment: God, I should have tried that !
It's working like a charm.
Thank you. But I would know why I have to This manually..

Comment: You're welcome, its manual because it does not always work as a filter, would be much better if it did.